# Can match on Result here be replaced with map_err and "?"

Tags: rust

I have some code which looks like this (greatly simplified version). A function takes two function arguments of type `LoadClient` and `CheckApproval` and returns either an error or a string.

```
pub struct Client {
    pub id: String,
}

pub enum MyErr {
    RequiresApproval(Client, String),
    LoadFailed,
}

pub fn authorize<LoadClient, CheckApproval>(load_client: LoadClient, check_approval: CheckApproval) -> Result<String, MyErr> 
where
   LoadClient: FnOnce(String) -> Result<Client, String>,
   CheckApproval: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a Client, &str) -> Result<&'a str, ()>,
{
    let client = load_client("hello".to_string()).map_err(|_| MyErr::LoadFailed)?;
    let permission = "something";

    // This doesn't compile
    // let authorized = check_approval(&client, permission).map_err(|_| MyErr::RequiresApproval(client, permission.to_string()))?;
    // Ok(authorized.to_string())

    // This version does
    match check_approval(&client, permission) {
        Err(_) => Err(MyErr::RequiresApproval(client, permission.to_string())),
        Ok(authorized) => Ok(authorized.to_string()),
    }
}
```

I'd like to used `?` with the `check_approval` call (as the commented out code shows) for simpler code and to avoid the extra nesting - the `Ok` branch in the final match is actually a much longer block.

Unfortunately that doesn't compile:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `client` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:19:66
   |
19 |     let authorized = check_approval(&client, permission).map_err(|_| MyErr::RequiresApproval(client, permission.to_string()))?;
   |                                     -------              ------- ^^^                         ------ move occurs due to use in closure
   |                                     |                    |       |
   |                                     |                    |       move out of `client` occurs here
   |                                     |                    borrow later used by call
   |                                     borrow of `client` occurs here
```

These seem similar (to my untrained eye). Hasn't the borrowed reference to `client` been returned by the time `map_err` is called?

My main question: Is there a way to get round this and write the code without using `match`?

[rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4f0cf4f6e1f91f344d4c75dc8eb6b23d).

Comment: No you can't because of your lifetime constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your two versions of the code are semantically equivalent, they are actually quite different for the compiler.

The failing one calls `Result::map_err()` with a closure that captures the value of `client`. That is, `client` is moved into the closure, but it is borrowed when calling `check_approval()`. And here lies the error, a borrowed value cannot be moved.

You may think that this borrow should finish when the function returns, but that is not the case because of its return type `Result<&'a str, ()>`, being `'a` precisely the lifetime of that borrow. The borrow of `client` is extended for as long as this `'a` exists. And that is why your second version works: when you match your `Result`, the `'a` does not extend to the `Err(())` branch, only to the `Ok(&'a str)` so the `Err(())` is able to move `client` freely.

> Is there a way to get round this and write the code without using `match`?

Well, you are calling `authorized.to_string()` in the returned `&'a str` and converting it to an owned `String`. So, if you can change your `CheckApproval` constraint to:

```rust
CheckApproval: FnOnce(&Client, &str) -> Result<String, ()>,
```

the problem just goes away.

If you cannot change that, another option is to do the `to_string()` before moving the `client` into the closure, finishing the borrow before it can do harm:

```rust
let authorized = check_approval(&client, permission)
    .map(|a| a.to_string())
    .map_err(|_| MyErr::RequiresApproval(client, permission.to_string()))?;
Ok(authorized)
```

Comment: Thanks! The return value isn't actually a string but an array of enum values, derived from the client, which is why I think I ended up with the lifetime parameter like that - this just got lost in trying to find a simple example with the same problem. Your answer makes it clearer what's going on though, so I think I can just use the same approch and change my function to return a `Vec` or something and clone the enum values as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the match statement to a functional expression in one go and thus also avoid the borrowing issue:

```rust
pub fn authorize<LoadClient, CheckApproval>(
    load_client: LoadClient,
    check_approval: CheckApproval,
) -> Result<String, MyErr>
where
    LoadClient: FnOnce(String) -> Result<Client, String>,
    CheckApproval: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a Client, &str) -> Result<&'a str, ()>,
{
    let client = load_client("hello".to_string()).map_err(|_| MyErr::LoadFailed)?;
    let permission = "something";

    check_approval(&client, permission)
        .map(|authorized| authorized.to_string())
        .map_err(|_| MyErr::RequiresApproval(client, permission.to_string()))
}
```

This way you do not need the `?` operator or a temporary variable.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this changes much from the original version or rodrigo's last suggestion though. As I said, this was a greatly simplified version. The motivation for using `?` was to be able to short-circuit after a failed call to `check_approval` and then continue with the main logic which would be what was currently in the Ok block, improving the readability of the code (in reality it didn't just return a string). I gave up on this approach (trying to program Rust with higher-order functions) when I had to make the code async. It was just too hard :). Interesting looking back though.