# Replacing a trait bound with a trait alias says "the size for values cannot be known at compilation time"

Tags: rust

After reading about [trait aliases](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/trait-alias.html), I tried to switch this code:

```
pub fn authorize<LoadClient>(get_client: LoadClient) -> Result<String, ()> 
where
   LoadClient: FnOnce(String) -> Result<Client, LoadingError>,
{
    unimplemented!()
}
```

to

```
#![feature(trait_alias)]

trait LoadClient = FnOnce(String) -> Result<Client, ClientLoadingError>;

pub fn authorize(get_client: LoadClient) -> Result<String, ()> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
warning: trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated
   --> src/oauth2/mod.rs:396:21
    |
396 |         get_client: LoadClient,
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^ help: use `dyn`: `dyn LoadClient`
    |
    = note: `#[warn(bare_trait_objects)]` on by default

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::ops::FnOnce(std::string::String) -> std::result::Result<oauth2::Client, oauth2::ClientLoadingError> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/oauth2/mod.rs:396:9
    |
396 |         get_client: LoadClient,
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
```

Is it possible to use a trait alias in this way? This function is used elsewhere so it would be nice to have a shared definition rather than redefine it at each place it's used.

This is related to [Can match on Result here be replaced with map_err and "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59698474/can-match-on-result-here-be-replaced-with-map-err-and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to use it as generic parameter:

```
#![feature(trait_alias)]

pub trait LoadClient = FnOnce(String) -> Result<Client, ClientLoadingError>;

pub fn authorize<T>(get_client: T) -> Result<String, ()>
where
    T: LoadClient,
{
    unimplemented!()
}
```

You also need to make the trait alias public since it is part of a public interface.

Comment: Thanks. I realized this shortly after and tried the same as you have, then found the`impl` syntax which is apparently syntactic sugar for the same thing. So I think the two are equivalent. I also got the compiler error about the trait alias not being public but forgot to mention that :).

Answer (score 1):

It seems this was just a naive mistake related to using traits as arguments, rather than anything specific to trait aliases. I need to use `impl LoadClient` as described in the [rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-02-traits.html?highlight=impl#traits-as-parameters) when using traits as function parameters.

With the signature

```
pub fn authorize(get_client: impl LoadClient) -> Result<String, ()>
```

the code compiles.