# Why doesn't lifetime elision work for traits

Tags: rust, traits

I would like to create my own trait, which should yield a `i32` based onindexing with a `f32`. I tried the following, which does seem to work:

```
use std::ops::Index;
// trait by value
pub trait MyTrait:
    Index<f32, Output=i32> {
}
```

While passing an `f32` by value may be a good idea, for more complicated types I would rather pass a reference to the value instead, so I tried the following:

```
// trait by reference, not compiling
pub trait MyTrait:
    Index<&f32, Output=i32> {
}
```

Including this definition gives me an `error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier`. I got this variant working:

```
// trait by reference, compiling
pub trait MyTrait<'a>:
    Index<&'a f32, Output=i32> {
}
```

Problem is: While this approach works, it means any type implementing `MyTrait` needs an explicit lifetime argument.

However, this seems rather unnecessary: If I implement the `Index` trait for my own struct I don't need any lifetimes:

```
struct Test {
  value: i32
}

impl Index<&f32> for Test {
  type Output = i32;

  fn index(&self, _key: &f32) -> &Self::Output {
    &self.value
  }
}
```

Question 1: Why do I need the additional lifetime in the definition of the trait, why can't it be elided?

Question 2: Can I define the trait in such a way as to avoid having to introduce the lifetime?

Comment: OK, I edited the question. The associated type is not really necessary for a MWE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I need the additional lifetime in the definition of the trait, why can't it be elided?

[Lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) is only applied to *function signature*. So no it won't work for your trait definition.

> Can I define the trait in such a way as to avoid having to introduce the lifetime?

Certainly, you can use generic parameter just as what [`std::ops::Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html) does:

```
use std::ops::Index;
pub trait MyTrait<T>: Index<T, Output = i32> {}

struct Test {
    value: i32,
}

impl Index<&f32> for Test {
    type Output = i32;

    fn index(&self, _key: &f32) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.value
    }
}

impl MyTrait<&f32> for Test {}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the first part. Regarding the second: I would like to have the trait as a shorthand. Instead of passing `T where T : Index<&f32, Output=i32>` around functions, I would like to use `T where T: MyTrait`. Just image that the supertrait is a lot more complex...

Comment: @hfhc2 in that case, passing `T: MyTrait<&f32>` around will do. As a side note, there's a unstable feature trait alias to do just that. See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720444/replacing-a-trait-bound-with-a-trait-alias-says-the-size-for-values-cannot-be-k/59720554#59720554) for an example. But alas, it is still unstable.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell (and I'm not 100% sure, the docs are rather silent on this), this:

```
impl Index<&f32> for Test { /* ... */ }
```

is shorthand for this:

```
impl <'a> Index<&'a f32> for Test { /* ... */ }
```

In other words, you implement the trait for *any* lifetime.

Analogously, you can require that the trait is implemented for any lifetime in your bound:

```
pub trait MyTrait:
    for<'a> Index<&'a f32, Output = i32> {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I would only add, for people who want to know more about this feature, that the `for<'a>` syntax is called a *higher-ranked trait bound* (HRTB). See also [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/3650362)

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you recommend a source for these advanced lifetimes?

Comment: @hfhc2 The [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/)